# I need to count the number of images from each album

Tags: php, laravel, join

I need to show the number of images that user's each album has. For that I assume I need another join or a subquery but I'm not being able to achive the result I want.

```
$userId = auth()->user()->id;
$albums = DB::table('users_albums')
        ->join('albums', 'users_albums.albumId', '=', 'albums.id')
        ->where('users_albums.userId', $userId)
        ->select('albums.name', 
            'albums.owner', 
            'albums.id', 
            'albums.created_at')
        ->get();
```

Database structure:

[image]

EDIT:Added the following code and it worked. The issue now would be performance, but the main one is solved!

```
DB::raw('(SELECT 
    COUNT(I.id) 
FROM 
    images I
WHERE
    I.albumId = albums.id) as numberOfImages')
```

Comment: Are you using Eloquent? Also what is your database schema so we can see the tables?

Comment: yes @GeorgeHanson, Im using Eloquent. Added a link to an image with the structure on the question. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have your Eloquent models set up for each table?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eloquent and Models, you could quite easily do this using `->count()`.

Without Eloquent, you could look into something along these lines:

(These are obviously not EXACTLY what you need, but should guide you down the right path)

```php
$album = DB::table('albums')->first();
$image_count = DB::table('images')->where('album_id', $album->id)->count();
```

More "eloquent" way:

```php
// Album model:

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}

public function getImageCount()
{
    return $this->images->count();
}

// Controller

$first_album = auth()->user()->albums->first();
$album_image_count = $first_album->getImageCount();
```

`hasManyThrough()` is another Eloquent method you shouldn't overlook :)

Comment: Sorry, still lost. The output should be an a list of objects that will say e.g. 
Item 1:
    Album 1
    5 images
Item 2:
    Album 2
    15 images

With your answer I still dunno how I can achieve that. I believe the answer should be in some sort of join with the images table...

Comment: You could simply add the `getImageCount()` method above to an appended attribute. Then whenever you retrieve a collection of albums, you'll have an image_count property?